# Como melhorar a otimização do código em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Escrevi uma função que recebe uma lista de números positivos ou negativos e retorna a soma de todos os números que são divisíveis por números primos e o número primo em questão. Exemplo:

funcao = [12, 15] # resultado = [[2, 12], [3, 27], [5, 15]]

[2,12] = Apenas o 12 é divisível por 2, e 2 é primo

[3,27] = Os números 12 e 15 são divisíveis por 3, sua soma é 27, e 3 é primo
E assim por diante.

Meu código está funcionando mas ele está demorando muito para executar quando os números são muito grandes, como eu posso otimizá-lo?

```
def checkprimo(n):
for x in range(n):
    if x+1!=1 and x+1!=n and n%(x+1)==0: return False
return True
def sum_for_list(lst):
nReply = []
for x in range(len(lst)):
    nReply.append([y+1 for y in range(lst[x] if lst[x]>0 else lst[x]*-1) if lst[x]%(y+1)==0])
reply = sorted(set([y for x in nReply for y in x] ))
if 1 in reply: reply.remove(1)
chose = []
for i,x in enumerate(reply):
    chose.append([0,0])
    for y in lst:
        if y%x==0 and checkprimo(x)==True:
            chose[i]=[x,y+(chose[i][1])]
for x in range(chose.count([0,0])):
    chose.remove([0,0])
return chose
```

Answer (score -2):

Não sei bem se é isso que você precisa, removi alguns loops desnecessários, e usei uma formula otimizada para detectar se é Primo.

Objetive esse resultado:

**Para 12,15** = [[2, 12], [3, 27], [5, 15]]

> Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) 0:00:00.391751

**Para 141412,1000002,12202001** =
[[2, 1141414], [35353, 141412], [3, 1000002], [166667, 1000002], [7, 12202001], [1743143, 12202001]]

> Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) 0:00:01.305071

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
  for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
    if (n%i) == 0:
      return False
  return True

def sum_for_list(lst):
    new_reply = []
    for x in lst:
        for y in range(2,abs(x)):
            if abs(x)%y == 0:
                if is_prime(y):
                    added  = False
                    for idx,value in enumerate(new_reply):
                        if y == value[0]:
                            new_reply[idx] = [y, x + value[1]]
                            added = True
                            break
                    if not added: new_reply.append([y,x])
    return new_reply

from datetime import datetime 
start_time = datetime.now() 

lst = [12,15]
sum_for_list(lst)

print('Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) {}'.format(datetime.now() - start_time ))
```